# Which mod showed me my tool's durability?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I've been toying around with *Test Pack Please Ignore* and I noticed one of its mods shows on my UI the remaining durability of whatever tool or item I'm holding. Which mod does this?

[image: Example Image of UI]

Comment: Not sure about the mod, but if you hit F3+h, it will turn on the durability display in the item tooltip when you mouse over it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty sure that's [Armor Staus HUD](http://www.minezone.pro/download/mods/16097-164-armorstatushud.html) (non-english site), also found on the [Minecraft Forum](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1114612-172-bspkrs-mods-armorstatushud-directionhud-statuseffecthud/), which provides a heads-up display for both armor and tools with durability (by adding a swing counter).

If by chance it's not the *exact* mod you have, ASH does the exact same thing that it does.